# put date in view for showing the last update

Tags: php, database, laravel, bootstrap-4

how i can put a date of last actualization in my view using laravel? i try use updated_at and carbon

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::now() }}
```

but a needed of the last update of my database or maybe using boostrap 4, appreciated ansewers.

Comment: What do you mean by 'last actualization'?

Comment: No worries. Just a tip English-wise, in the US we do "ok" or "kk" but not "kkk" becuase that's an abbreviation for a bad organization here in the states.

Comment: yes and truth my apologies for this mistake i will delete that comment, thanks for the help!

Comment: As last update from database you mean all tables or a specific table? Does this/these tables have models?

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I already managed to perform this function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two separate actions. On your first query, you'd save it like this:

```
$model->updated_at = Carbon::now();
```

Then later when you fetch it from the database, display it like this:

```
echo (new Carbon($model->updated_at)->format('DD YYYY'));
```